# Firestore: What is the best way to populate array of ids with its content?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have array of objects containing users Ids.

```
const userIDs= [{key: 'user_1'},{key: 'user_2'}, {key: 'user_3'}];
```

I want to fill it with user data from cloud firestore.

```
const userIDs= [
{key: 'user_1', name: 'name1'},
{key: 'user_2', name: 'name2'}, 
{key: 'user_3', name: 'name3'}
];
```

What is the fastest and less pricey way of doing it ?

This is my current way of doing it.

```
      const filledUsers = [];
            for (let index in userIDs) {
                const user = Object.assign({}, concatUsers[index]);
                const snapshot = await usersRef.doc(user.key).get();
                filledUsers.push(Object.assign(user, snapshot.data()));
            })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `await` inside the for loop is inefficient. Instead, it's best to use `Promise.all` on list of executed `ref.get()` and then `await`.

If you need to reduce the price, you need to apply caching.

See source code below.

```
// module 'db/users.js'

const usersRef = db.collection('users');

export const getUsers = async (ids = []) => {
    let users = {};

    try {
        users = (await Promise.all(ids.map(id => usersRef.doc(id).get())))
            .filter(doc => doc.exists)
            .map(doc => ({ [doc.id]: doc.data() }))
            .reduce((acc, val) => ({ ...acc, ...val }), {});

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`received an error in getUsers method in module \`db/users\`:`, error);
        return {};

    }

    return users;
}

// Usage:
//
// (await getUsers(['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3']))
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks awesome!
How would you map it to array ?

Comment: @Alexandr, `const usersArray = Object.keys(usersMap).map(userId => ({ userId, ...usersMap[id] }));`